# Toasting "To the Old Gods"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I have been trying to find information regarding toasts however I am just starting my studying of German. I would like to be able to toast the Old Nordic gods when I have drink, but lack of knowledge has prevented me from finding a concrete answer and as always Google Translate is almost worthless for German.

Comment: There is a risk that toasting to Nordic or Germanic Gods will be frowned upon in Germany coming from the (Neo-)Nazi affection to Germanic mythology.

Comment: That is why I wanted to know what "the old gods" meant instead of Nordic gods, because it actually is more accurate to me. As per the frowning upon I am not so sure about I would have to ask my friend from Germany about that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would say a toast to Odin, just say:

> Auf Odin!

while you rise your glass.

If you would like to say a toast to the old gods, say:

> Auf die alten Götter!

Comment: And if I wanted to say Nordic it would be `Nordischen` correct?

Comment: Yes. But be aware that nordic gods (nordische Götter) and celtic gods (keltische Götter) and germanic gods (germanische Götter) are not the same gods! And "old gods" can also be aegyptan, greec, roman, hebrew or many other gods! But this is off topic.

Comment: All the old gods would suffice, if I wanted to get specific I could specify them specifically by name, otherwise `the old gods` will be just fine, thanks!